# Textbook search: learning the math required to read the newspaper

Tags: undergraduate-education, textbooks

TL;DR: do you know of an undergrad textbook that covers numeracy with an emphasis on genuine context (as opposed to the artificial word problems that are all too common)?

---

Less concisely:

I am an instructor in the US, teaching in a large, research  university. I am looking for a textbook that teaches numeracy at the college-level (so above the level of algebra 2) to students who need math courses for their degree, but have limited interest in the subject.

More specifically: I am looking for a book that teaches the students different skills (logical, statistical, etc) for analyzing the math that appears in the newspaper.

I am aware of books like "A Mathematician Reads the Newspaper," and I would be happy to find other books like this, but am hoping to discover a **textbook** on or near this topic.

Answer (score 6):

I've heard good things about Bolker and Mast's [Common Sense Mathematics](http://www.maa.org/press/books/common-sense-mathematics), though I haven't used it myself.  I can't imagine the MAA wouldn't send you a review copy in your situation.

Answer (score 3):

Not direct answers (not textbooks), but there have been several books published recently on estimation that might serve as background:

> Weinstein, Lawrence, and John A. Adam. *Guesstimation: Solving the world's problems on the back of a cocktail napkin*. Princeton, NJ, USA: Princeton University Press, 2009.
>
> ---
>
> [image]
>
> ---
>
> Weinstein, Lawrence. *Guesstimation 2.0: Solving today's problems on the back of a napkin*. Princeton University Press, 2012.
>
> ---
>
> Mahajan, Sanjoy, and Carver A. Mead. *Street-fighting mathematics: The art of educated guessing and opportunistic problem solving*. MIT Press, 2010.